# How to find second runner up score?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```py
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
setA = set(arr)

for x in setA:
    x.sorted()
    print(x)
```

## Here is the error that I am facing

```py
5
9 8 7 4
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jnnim\OneDrive\Desktop\hacker rank\practice\untitled1.py", line 6, in <module>
    x.sorted()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sorted'
```

## Requirements for the program

You are given n scores. Store them in a list and find the score of the runner-up.

The first line contains n elements. The second line contains an array of integers each separated by a space.

In this program for loop, I have tried that within `setA`, because we have to sort `setA`.

I had made the array in set because it does not keeps duplicate element.

6. Finally when I have to find out the runner up score then I will call [-1] index and make it print as runner up score.
7. If you need to know more about question please comment, I will tell you anything you need.
8. Please help me solve this error in this program only within these lines. Don't give a full solution

Comment: First off, it's ```sorted(x)```, not `x.sorted`. Second of all, you can sort a list, not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's `sorted(x)`, not `x.sorted`. Second of all, you can sort a list, not a number.

You need to do this: `x = sorted(setA)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
arrset = set(arr)
runnerup = 0
for index, val in enumerate(sorted(arrset), start=1):
    if index == len(arrset) - 1:
        runnerup = val
print(runnerup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
arr = (int, input().split())


arrlist = [] 

for t in arr:  
    arrlist.append(t)     
num=arrlist[1]

test_list = [int(i) for i in num]
test_sorted= (sorted(test_list, reverse=True))
List = []
for i in test_sorted:
    if i != max(test_sorted):
        List.append(i)
        
print(max(List))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
arr = (int, input().split())

new_arr=[]
for x in arr:
  if x not in new_arr:
    new_arr.append(x)
    
max_arr = max(new_arr)
new_arr.remove(max_arr)
    
runnerup_arr = max(new_arr)
    
print(runnerup_arr)
```